# IONIC 2 send message to multiple recipients

Tags: android, ionic2, sms

So developing this IONIC 2 app, I discoverd that sending SMS to multiple recipients isnt so trivial at it should be.

After a long research I've found [this](https://github.com/cordova-sms/cordova-sms-plugin/issues/14) post where people trys to deal with multiple SMS. But even using their specs it doesnt work properly.

They say we can use an array of strings representing multiple phone numbers. So far so good, except it works only for the first number.

If someone has now details on this functionality I would love to hear about it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after ages of research over internet I got this litle jam called [cordova-plugin-sms](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-sms) ( dont confuse it with cordova-sms-plugin ).

As it says in their documentation they have a function sendSMS which reeeally sends messages to multiple recipients.

So my solution for integrating it in IONIC 2 is as follows :

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-sms
```

and my Ionic 2 class is :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http, Response } from "@angular/http";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

declare let window: any; 

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {

    constructor(private toastCtrl: ToastController, public navCtrl: NavController, public http: Http ) { }

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        this.startWhatchSMS();
    }

    // Android ONLY
    startWhatchSMS() {
        if (window.SMS) {
            window.SMS.startWatch(() => {
                //console.log("startWatch");
            }, error => {
                //console.log(error);
                //console.log("error startWatch");
            });
        }
        document.addEventListener('onSMSArrive', this.smsArived);
    }

    // Android ONLY
    smsArived = (result: any) => {

        //console.log(result);
        let sms = result.data;

        // put your code here...

    }

    sendTextMessage( ) {

        window.SMS.sendSMS([ '1234567890' , '0987654321' ], 'Text message for multiple recipients',
        (result) => {

            console.log(result); // should be 'OK' string


        }, (error) => {

            console.log(error);

        });

    }

}
```

The sendTextMessage() function is called from the template by clicking an button.

Well thats it ... for me is working and hope will work for you too.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

```
import { SMS } from '@ionic-native/sms';
constructor(  private sms: SMS ){
 this.sendSMS();
 }
sendSMS() {
var MultiNumber = [ '1234567890' , '9876543210' ];
this.sms.send(MultiNumber, 'hello all this is testing message');
}
```

try this it is working for me, Hope it is working for you too.

Comment: No Jaydeep ... unfortunatelly this is not working corectly for me ... I already tryed this and it sends only to the first recipient in array

Comment: then send one by one number multiple times. `this.sms.send('123456789', 'hello all this is testing message')` .  `this.sms.send('9876543210', 'hello all this is testing message')`